# Magento2 Renew Certification experience for professional certificate

Tags: magento2

I am nearby expiring my professional certificate. I checked this link

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/certification/program/technical-certifications/ac/ac-renew.html?lang=en

Just wanted to know how was the experience with only 3 attempts per month.

And passing marks seems to be working described

Passing Score: 228/37

Please share the feedback & study material if any

Comment: How many months you have to renew ?

Comment: 3 months to renew existing

Comment: Do you have any experience on that?

Comment: Yep I recently re certified

Comment: How much was the passing marks? How where the questions type same as 1 time